# Module not found error in Anaconda terminal

Tags: python, module, anaconda

Can somebody please explain why this is happening?

```
(base) C:\Users\Harry\Desktop>pip show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.17.4
Summary: NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: c:\users\harry\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: tensorflow-hub, tensorflow-gpu, tensorboard, tables, statsmodels, seaborn, scikit-learn, resampy, PyWavelets, pytest-arraydiff, pyclustering, patsy, pandas, opt-einsum, numexpr, numba, mkl-random, mkl-fft, matplotlib, librosa, langid, Keras, Keras-Preprocessing, Keras-Applications, imageio, h5py, Bottleneck, bokeh, bkcharts, audiosegment, astropy

(base) C:\Users\Harry\Desktop>script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

`numpy` is installed as you can see, but python can't import it. Why is this?